# Wordpress: Change content of div based on price

Tags: php, wordpress

Trying to make .php changes to return a string: "Verkocht" when the item's price is "1".

Original working code:

```
<span class="b-goods-1__price_th text-primary visible-th">';
            if( $validate['auto-price_show'] ):
            $price = is_numeric($this->get_meta('_auto_price')) || $this->get_meta('_auto_price') == ''  ? $this->get_price() : $auto_translate[$this->get_price()];
                $pixad_out .= wp_kses_post($price);

            endif;
    $pixad_out .= '
</span>
```

My attempt to return a string "Verkocht" when I enter "1" as price.

```
<span class="b-goods-1__price_th text-primary visible-th">';
             if( $validate['auto-price_show'] ):
            $price = is_numeric($this->get_meta('_auto_price')) || $this->get_meta('_auto_price') == ''  ? $this->get_price() : $auto_translate[$this->get_price()];
                and wp_kses_post($price) == 1){
                    echo '<div class="b-goods-1__price_th text-primary visible-th">Verkocht</div>';
                }else{
             echo $pixad_out .= wp_kses_post($price);
                }
            endif;
$pixad_out .= '

</span>
```

Comment: and wp_kses_post($price) == 1){ should be  if (wp_kses_post($price) == 1){

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working

```
<span class="b-goods-1__price_th text-primary visible-th">';
            if( $validate['auto-price_show'] ):
            $price = is_numeric($this->get_meta('_auto_price')) || $this->get_meta('_auto_price') == ''  ? $this->get_price() : $auto_translate[$this->get_price()];

            if($this->get_meta('_auto_price') == 1){
                $pixad_out .= 'Verkocht';
            }else{
                $pixad_out .= wp_kses_post($price); 
            }

            endif;
$pixad_out .= '
</span>
```